# Configuring WCF Services in Windows 8.1 Store app

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-runtime

I am working on a windows store app that consumes some WCF services. My project is designed as follows:

1. Windows Universal App (only concerned with the Windows 8.1 app right
   now though)
2. Portable Class Library with all of my repository objects in it.
     These are going to talk to my services
3. WCF Services (approx 15 of them)

I also have 3 different environments:

1. My Local computer
2. A non prod Azure Cloud environment
3. A Prod Azure Cloud environment

My problem is this: normally I would put my client configuration in a web.config or app.config file. Then I would set up multiple config transformations that change the addresses/bindings for each environment. Unfortunately, these are not supported in Windows 8.1 store apps. I know I can define the client programmatically rather than through configuration, but how can I then change configuration based on environment (without having to litter my code with `if(Environment == "Dev"...`)?

Comment: You can't put the information in the app.xaml file?  (I've only done a little with Windows 8.1 apps, and that was several months ago).

Comment: The app.xaml file is not a config file, but is the start of the program. I could register the clients in my IoC from the app.xaml file, but that wouldn't really help with the multiple environment problem.